# Grant Keycloak client service user permission to manage only its own client

Tags: permissions, keycloak

I would assign the service user of a Keycloak client the permission to edit only his own client (e.g. set the backchannel redirect url, as well as edit the valid redirect urls).
I have already enabled the preview feature “fine grained permissions” using “keycloak.profile.feature.admin_fine_grained_authz=enabled”. How do I add the permission to the service user?

Comment: Would this able to help? https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_client_registration

Comment: @TonyYip Thanks for the tip. I had not thought about this approach before. I would have to rebuild my application to do this. I will test this, but it sounds very promising. Currently, an "admin" client creates the new clients and they should then change their configuration themselves afterwards. The approach that the apps create a client themselves is definitely more sustainable. Nevertheless, I would like to know how these fine grained permissions work.

Answer (score 1):

You can Add roles to user from `Users - - > Select User - - > Role Mappings - - - > Client Roles - - > Select Realm(Realm Management) - - > Assign Required Roles(manage-users, manage-realms...)` 
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not what I want to achieve. There, only rights on realm level can be assigned. So I can give users only the permission to edit ALL clients. But only the service user of a client should be able to edit his client.